# Expanded GUI for openCV with python and conda

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda, conda

I'm using **opencv 3.3** with **python3.6.3** that I installed in a **conda** environment and for a while, when displaying images (with the basic cv2 function `imshow("window name", my_image)` for example) a small GUI would be displayed with the image. I was also able to zoom in and out at will and even go as far as being able to see the RGB intensities of each of the image's pixels.

That was pretty handy, but I recently updated my opencv version with conda (`3.3.0 -> 3.3.1`) and the feature is gone. Downgrading the cv2 module doesn't bring the feature back.

I've gathered, from what I've found, that one can manually enable this feature by adding the flag `cv2.WINDOW_GUI_EXPANDED` whilst creating the window but it does not change anything on the displayed window.

I managed to print all the available flags in cv2 (with `>>help(cv2)` on python) and that particular flag doesn't seem to be set :

[image: Python cv2 help screenshot]

Apparently, one should build opencv with Qt in order to gain access to that flag, but is that possible with conda?

While looking at the opencv Documentation you can see that they feature both `EXPANDED` (below) and `NORMAL` (above) GUI

[image: OpenCV documentation]

How could I set this flag to work with my current opencv version? Or do I need to build my cv2 module with Qt on conda? And if yes, how so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Qt GUI is fantastic by comparison, Simply build opencv with qt and install it into the conda enviroment